# .length on DIV of a class doesn't work if they were fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
 $('.entry').fadeOut();
 console.log($('.entry').length);
```

So even if the DIV of   `entry` class is not show for some reason it's still counted as if it's there.

Does anybody know how I could count the number of elements of a class correctly, so it even works if they were hidden with fadeOut?

Comment: fading out element doesn't remove it from the DOM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `:visible` pseudo-selector. It'll select all elements that are visible.

```
console.log($('.entry:visible').length);
```

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

**Edit**

Make sure you'll use this after the element is completely `faded`. i.e. inside the `fadeOut` callback.

```
$('.entry').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    console.log($('.entry:visible').length);
});
```

Comment: @deemeetree If this has helped you to solve problem please accept this answer